# How to show Axios response data into DataTable using Jquery

Tags: axios, datatable, ejs

Hello guys i have this problem i have been trying to fix for days now.
Am making a post request to my PHP server to fetch results from database. Now am using JS map function to populate the results into table.

Am using DataTable which populates and show results but when i try to search for Student using DataTable search everything disappears and show "No Results Found"

Need help to make pagination and search, sorting work.

i have provided my script and html code below

student.ejs //HTML page containing students table

```
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Name</th>
          <th class="text-center">Index No</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
     
     <tbody id="tableData" class="text-center"></tbody>

   </table>  

<!-- fetch -->
<script>

  axios.get('myFetchAPIHere')
 .then(function(response){

    let finalData = response.data;

    let tableData = "";
    finalData.map((values) => {

        tableData += `<tr class='text-center'>`;

        tableData += `<td class='fw-bolder text-dark'>${values.fullname}</td>`;
        tableData += `<td class='text-primary fw-bolder'>${values.index_no}</td>`;

        tableData += `</tr>`;
    });
    document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = tableData;
    
 })
 .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
 })


</script>

<script>
 // Jquery Datatable
 let jquery_datatable = $("#table1").DataTable({)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Order of Execution

You have two scripts in your page. The second script initializes your JavaScript datatable:

```
$("#table1").DataTable();
```

However, it is being executed *before* the first script finishes.

This means that DataTables finds an empty `<html>` table - and therefore the DataTable contains no data. When you perform any DataTables operation such as filtering or sorting, DataTables re-displays its data - which is *no data at all*.

Your first script *starts* before your second script starts... but the first thing it does is to issue an Ajax call using your axios library. This is an *asynchronous* event - so it *waits* for the response before it executes its `.then` function.

While it is waiting for that callback, the second script runs (as described above).

Now, after the Ajax call has returned its data, your first script builds the HTML table - and that is what you get to see in your web page.

It's not showing you a DataTable - it's just showing you a raw HTML table. And (as noted already) that is why all its data disappears as soon as you try to use the DataTable.

#### Quick Fix

The simplest fix is to delete that second script, and then place the following line...

```
let jquery_datatable = $("#table1").DataTable();
```

...inside the `.then` function, at the very end:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  axios.get('myFetchAPIHere')
 .then(function(response) {
      let finalData = response.data;

      let tableData = "";
      finalData.map((values) => {
        tableData += `<tr class='text-center'>`;
        tableData += `<td class='fw-bolder text-dark'>${values.fullname}</td>`;
        tableData += `<td class='text-primary fw-bolder'>${values.index_no}</td>`;
        tableData += `</tr>`;
      });
      document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = tableData;
      // place the DataTables initialization command here:
      let jquery_datatable = $("#table1").DataTable();
    }); // note how the above command MUST BE INSIDE the "then" function

});
</script>
```

Note how I have also wrapped everything inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... }` - so that no JavaScript starts running until the page is ready.

---

If you are interested, you can prove to yourself what is happening with your existing code, by adding `console.log()` statements to your code.

For example:

```js
<script>
 
  console.log( 'step 1: ' + Date.now() );

  axios.get('myFetchAPIHere')
 .then(function(response){

    console.log( 'step 2: ' + Date.now() );

    let finalData = response.data;

    let tableData = "";
    finalData.map((values) => {

        tableData += `<tr class='text-center'>`;

        tableData += `<td class='fw-bolder text-dark'>${values.fullname}</td>`;
        tableData += `<td class='text-primary fw-bolder'>${values.index_no}</td>`;

        tableData += `</tr>`;
    });
    document.getElementById('tableData').innerHTML = tableData;

    console.log( 'step 3: ' + Date.now() );
    
 })
 .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error);
 })


</script>

<script>
 // Jquery Datatable

 console.log( 'step 4: ' + Date.now() );

 let jquery_datatable = $("#table1").DataTable({)

 console.log( 'step 5: ' + Date.now() );
</script>
```

Take a look at what order the steps are printed in the browser's console (F12 to open).

Comment: Just to add a footnote: DataTables has built-in support for Ajax. This means (if you do it right) you can avoid all of that tedious logic to build strings of HTML data. See [Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html) and also because you are using axios, see [ajax source as a custom function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax). You still need to handle adding custom classes to your table, but DataTables has support for that also.

Comment: Tried the fix didn't so i used ajax instead of axios to pull the data. am posting the fix to help anyone who will need it

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix I found:

I deleted the Axios call and used Ajax as suggested by **andrewJames**

```js
<script>
   
    // Jquery Datatable
    let jquery_datatable = $("#table1").DataTable({
    
        ajax:{
            url:"Your API CALL",
            type: "GET",
            dataSrc:"",
        },
                
               
        // fetch all the columns in your json object array
        "columns" :[
            {"data" : "fullname"},
            {"data" : "index_no"}
        ]
    })
</script>
```

Comment: <script>
    let loadDatatableAxios = new DataTable('#elmntID',{
        ajax:async function(obj,fn){
            let retval = await axios.get(URL_ADDRESS);
            return fn({data:retval.data});
        },
        columnDefs:[...],
    })
</script>